# How to test oAuth2 with supertest and jest

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, openid, supertest

I have an application authorizing with different OpenId-Autorization services (e.g. salesforce, google-login, ms-teams etc.)

Now I wanted to implement testing and I tried to mock the authentication workflow with a standalone server (https://github.com/navikt/mock-oauth2-server)

I use the standard openID client (https://www.npmjs.com/package/openid-client)

```
/**
 * /AUTH TESTS
 */

describe('GET the auth route', () => {
    test('return 302 when redirect correctly', async () => {
        const response = await api
            .get('/auth')
            .query({ user: 'tester@test.com', oauth: 'testoauth2'})
            .set('Authorization', `${token}`)
            .expect(302)
    })
})

describe('GET the authcallback route', () => {
    test('return content when auth is successful', async () => {
        const response = await api
            .get('/authcallback')
            .set("Cookie", ['oauthKey=testoauth2; nonce=4DwCl4XuvRcckI_7Yv2smA0hnRxQtj2_mU1Q13NbU9A; codeVerifier=c-WoROhqZHBS13rSJ1ePd4O5p4W-_aqB1n3fJSjLXaU; user=tester@test.com' ])
            .set('Authorization', `${token}`)
            .query({
                code: "aPrxi6BfM_yOlkX6zB4nTDQCYgASP_69O.ZCuOWYNe7DyP2UxaNc5ZwtbDsPrG_wnUgvb3WJ8Q=="
            })

    })
})
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible in general to test a oAuth2 workflow with supertest?
2. What am I missing? The error is most of the time: "Nonce mismatch"

// edit:

Digged deeper into the problem and found out that its hard to test the oauth workflow with supertest. Maybe Cypress or TestCafe are better alternatives. Can anybody confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it myself

```
describe('test the whole oauth2 workflow', () => {
    test('correctly create new integration after complete workflow', async () => {
        let response = await api
            .get('/auth')
            .query({ user: 'tester@test.com', oauth: 'testoauth2'})
            .set('Authorization', `${token}`)
            .expect(302)

        let cookies = response.headers['set-cookie']

        // we need to try/catch the call to get the correct callback url with the code
        try {
            response = await axios
                .get(response.headers.location, {
                    headers: {
                        Cookie: response.headers['set-cookie']
                    }})
        } catch (e) {
            expect(e.request.path).toContain('authcallback')
           
            response = await api
                .get(e.request.path)
                .set("Cookie", cookies)
                .set('Authorization', `${token}`)
                .expect(200)
        }

        let integration = await api
            .get('/integration')
            .set('Authorization', `${token}`)
            .query({channel: 'testoauth2'})
            .expect(200)

        expect(integration.text.channel).toBe('testoauth2')
    })
})
```

a little bit hacky with the try catch but otherwise the cookies wouldn't be in the next request